MegaRAID HBA complaining on boot but can't reset
I have an ASUS Pike II 3018 card that recently had a physical failure - heatsink broke off chip (due to old plastic clip).  I have repaired the heatsink but on boot I see the error below.  I do NOT have a battery backup, yet it complains on each boot!  I tried pressing 'D' but it made no difference.
How do I clear the BBU error?  And what does the L2/L3 mean exactly?  Why is it reporting a cache error?


The MegaRAID box has some form of CPU in it. That CPU has failed; it's reporting errors in the CPU level-2 and/or level-3 cache in that CPU. Quite likely the heat sink was not making good contact with the CPU for some time and the CPU has overheated terminally. You can try pressing the X key to continue despite this, but if it was my system I'd be really unlikely to do that; if the CPU is throwing cache errors likely its parity calculations will be compromised and all the data on the RAID array is at risk.

I tried pressing X and it runs...(all drives seem accessible)...I will plan to migrate to a new raid solution.  Can I safely copy data from the RAID array through the existing card?  Or do I need to restore from a backup? (Which is OLD, sad to say)

In your situation, I would try copying through the existing card, but keep that old backup available, as there may be some data corruption during the copy process, and the backup, no matter its age, may have a good copy of the files that get damaged. It's possible that the system will fault with another cache error, in which case presumably you'll be able to restart the copy where you left off, but note the file where the fault happened because that's one that is at high risk of corruption.

I'm making a simple backup now (file copy) and so far no errors.  Would an error only appear if there was a checksum error?  In other words, so longs as the 2 disks match on read/write then there is no failure.  I'm running the RAID controller under ESXi 8, so I don't know how a controller error would be reported through ESXi.  Would I even see an error or would corrupt data just be copied.   I wish I knew what exactly the L2/L3 error meant (aside from the obvious)

Not having that controller, I can't know for certain. Problem is that with a CPU failure you can't be sure that a data mismatch will actually be properly detected. So erroneous data may be copied without complaint, and valid data may be flagged as an error... but I can't really know.

I tried flashing the card with the latest bios (5 years old) and that seemed to reset the card.  No more errors.  However, I don't trust it and will replace it anyways...but for other users who encounter this try to upgrade/reflash your raid card firmware.

An addition to the @tsc_chazz answer, but it's worth being an answer on its own:
Replace the card (the reason is explained). It's safe. The new card will see the array configured on existing drives and run it; depending on it's internal state, it might non need any actions, or, it might see your hard drives as containing foreign configuration and then you need to import it.
